# Javascript Error on p5.js (Unexpected end of input)

Tags: javascript, meteor, p5.js

I have a problem in p5.js. I was creating this for a school project, and everything works (I think). However, when I run it, it shows me "Unexpected end of input." And the error says "Unrecoverable syntax error (100% scanned). I'm not sure what's wrong.

I included the code below in case if there's something wrong with my code. Thanks for your time!

````
/* GLOBAL VARIABLES */
let meteorX = []; // Store X position of the meteor
let meteorY = [0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0]; // Store Y position of the meteor

let meteorDiameter = []; // Store diameter of the meteor
let catcherWidth = 40; // Store diameter of the catcher
let catcherHeight = 60


let distance; //distance between catcher and meteor
let speed = []; //Speed of meteor

let score = 0; //number of meteor caught

//Declare a variables to store the image files
let bgImage;
let meteorImage;
let catcherImage;

// Only runs once
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);  
  
  //Load the images into the sketch and store in variables
  bgImage = loadImage('bgImage.jpg');
  meteorImage = loadImage('meteor.png');
  catcherImage = loadImage('rocketship.png');
}
  
  //populate meteorX values
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    meteorX[i] = random(0, width);
  }


  //populate initial diameter  
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    meteorDiameter[i] = random(10,40)
  }

  //populate initial speed
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    speed[i] = random(0.5,4)
  }
  

// Runs over and over in a loop
function draw() {
  // Draws the image starting from the top left corner
  imageMode(CORNER);
  background(bgImage); 
  noStroke(); 
  
  //Draw meteors to screen
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ellipse(meteorX[i], meteorY[i], meteorDiameter[i],meteorDiameter[i])
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i <5; i++){
    meteorY[i] = meteorY[i] + speed[i]
  }
  
  // Draw the catcher to follow the mouse
  image(catcherImage, mouseX, mouseY, catcherWidth, catcherHeight);
  
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    distance[i] = dist(meteorX[i], meteorY[i], mouseX, mouseY);
    
  //whenever a meteor intersects with catcher
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(distance[i] < 15){
      meteorY[i] = 0
      meteorX[i] = random(0,width)
      
      meteorDiameter = random(10,40)
      
      score = score + 1
    }
  }
  
  //when meteor touches bottom of screen
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(distance[i] > height){
      meteorY[i] = 0;
      meteorX[i] = random(0, width);
      meteorDiameter[i] = random(10,40)
    }
  }
  
 
  
  // Test to see if cat has intersected with screen bottom
  if(meteorY > height) {
    meteorY = 0;
    meteorX = random(width);
    speed = random(1,4);
    meteorDiameter = random(10,30);
  }
  
  // put score on bottom
  fill(0, 254, 202);
  textAlign(RIGHT);
  textSize(15);
  text('Score: ' + score, 80, 385);
  
   if(score == 10){
    meteorY = width + 10;
    meteorX = height + 10;
    speed = 0;
    
    //win message
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(20);
    text('You Win!', width/2, height/2);
    textSize(14);
    text('Click the mouse anywhere to restart.', width/2, height/2 + 30);
    
    // Restart the game if player clicks the mouse.
    if(mouseIsPressed){
    restart();
    }
  }
} 
  
function restart(){
  meteorY = 0
  meteorX = 100
  speed = 0.5
  score = 0
}```
````

Comment: There's a missing `}` in this code; where is the end of your `draw` function?

Comment: This highlights how important it is to keep your code well formatted. Spotting something like that would have been a lot easier if the indentation was consistent.

Comment: Using a linter like prettier, eslint or standard would also help to detect such issues

Comment: I fixed it, but some new errors are popping in, do you guys know if you could help me?

Comment: I think you'll need to make a new post specific to the new errors. We don't know if we can help unless we have the details.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the draw function with }, you opened but not closed.

```js
function draw() {
  // Draws the image starting from the top left corner
  imageMode(CORNER);
  background(bgImage); 
  noStroke(); 
  
  //Draw meteors to screen
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ellipse(meteorX[i], meteorY[i], meteorDiameter[i],meteorDiameter[i])
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i <5; i++){
    meteorY[i] = meteorY[i] + speed[i]
  }
  
  // Draw the catcher to follow the mouse
  image(catcherImage, mouseX, mouseY, catcherWidth, catcherHeight);
  
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    distance[i] = dist(meteorX[i], meteorY[i], mouseX, mouseY);
    
  //whenever a meteor intersects with catcher
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(distance[i] < 15){
      meteorY[i] = 0
      meteorX[i] = random(0,width)
      
      meteorDiameter = random(10,40)
      
      score = score + 1
    }
  }
  
  //when meteor touches bottom of screen
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(distance[i] > height){
      meteorY[i] = 0;
      meteorX[i] = random(0, width);
      meteorDiameter[i] = random(10,40)
    }
  }
  
 
  
  // Test to see if cat has intersected with screen bottom
  if(meteorY > height) {
    meteorY = 0;
    meteorX = random(width);
    speed = random(1,4);
    meteorDiameter = random(10,30);
  }
  
  // put score on bottom
  fill(0, 254, 202);
  textAlign(RIGHT);
  textSize(15);
  text('Score: ' + score, 80, 385);
  
   if(score == 10){
    meteorY = width + 10;
    meteorX = height + 10;
    speed = 0;
    
    //win message
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(20);
    text('You Win!', width/2, height/2);
    textSize(14);
    text('Click the mouse anywhere to restart.', width/2, height/2 + 30);
    
    // Restart the game if player clicks the mouse.
    if(mouseIsPressed){
    restart();
        }
      }
    } 
} <--- This one is missing
```